# map is undefined error - higher order functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm testing higher order functions in JS, but keep getting an error 
' map is undefined' Can anyone help?

```
function mapper(f) {
    return function(a) { return map(a, f); };
}

var increment = function(x) { return x+1; };
var incrementer = mapper(increment);
incrementer([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is not a global function, but [a property of `Array`'s prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function mapper(f) {
    return function(a) { return a.map(f); };
}

var increment = function(x) { return x+1; };
var incrementer = mapper(increment);
var out = incrementer([1,2,3])

console.log(out); // [2,3,4]
```